# 'Inset Faces' is killing me. please help me!

Tags: modeling

I'm try to make a arch gate.

However, the increment is not applied evenly. 
[image]
This is what I'm trying to make.
[image]

What's the problem?
Please help.

Comment: What does it do if you apply the mirror modifier first so that the inset is working on complete geo and not being affected by the mirror?

Comment: are you talking about extrusion? not inset faces I guess...